# XSLT won't create correct number of rows upon transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am trying to create a XLST file from XML but the problem is when I transform the XSLT to HTML, the output is not as it is supposed to be. The problem is that when I run the transformation, I only get one row of Steps, that is only the first step is displayed and all the others are not. The output can be seen [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uUYI.png). The desired result can be found [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTED7.png)

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Recipe>    
    <Title>Beef Parmesan With Garlic Angel Hair Pasta</Title>    
    <Ingredients>
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Beef Cube Steak</Name>
            <Quantity>1 1/2 Pounds</Quantity>
            <Description>-</Description>
        </Ingredient>        
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Spaghetti Sauce</Name>
            <Quantity>One 16 Ounce Jar</Quantity>
            <Description>-</Description>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Onion</Name>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Description>Sliced Into Thin Rings</Description>
        </Ingredient>        
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Mozzarella Cheese</Name>
            <Quantity>1/2 Cup</Quantity>
            <Description>Shredded</Description>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Green Bell Pepper</Name>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Description>Sliced Into Rings</Description>
        </Ingredient>        
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Green Bell Pepper</Name>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Description>Sliced Into Rings</Description>
        </Ingredient>       
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Angel Hair Pasta</Name>
            <Quantity>12 Ounces</Quantity>
            <Description>-</Description>
        </Ingredient>        
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Bread Crumbs</Name>
            <Quantity>1 Cup</Quantity>
            <Description>Italian Seasoned</Description>
        </Ingredient>        
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Garlic</Name>
            <Quantity>2 Teaspoons</Quantity>
            <Description>Minced</Description>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Parmesan Cheese</Name>
            <Quantity>1/2 Cup</Quantity>
            <Description>Grated</Description>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Butter</Name>
            <Quantity>1/4 Cup</Quantity>
            <Description>-</Description>
        </Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>
            <Name>Olive Oil</Name>
            <Quantity>2 Tablespoons</Quantity>
            <Description>-</Description>
        </Ingredient>        
    </Ingredients>

    <Directions>        
        <Steps>
            <Step>1. Preheat oven to 350 degress Fahrenheit (175 degrees Celsius)</Step>
            <Step>2. Cut cube steak into serving size pieces</Step>
            <Step>3. Coat meat with the bread crumbs and parmesan cheese</Step>
            <Step>4. Heat olive oil in a large frying pan, and saute 1 teaspoon of the garlic for 3 minutes</Step>
            <Step>5. Quick fry (brown quickly on both sides) meat</Step>
            <Step>6. Place meat in a casserole baking dish, slightly overlapping edges</Step>
            <Step>7. Place onion rings and peppers on top of meat, and pour marinara sauce over all</Step>
            <Step>8. Bake at 350 degrees FFahrenheit (175 degrees Celsius) for 30 to 45 minutes, depending on the thickness of the meat</Step>
            <Step>9. Sprinkle mozzarella over meat and leave in the oven till bubbly</Step>
            <Step>10. Boil pasta al dente</Step>
            <Step>11. Drain, and toss in butter and 1 teaspoon garlic</Step>
            <Step>12. For a stronger garlic taste, season with garlic powder</Step>
            <Step>13. Top with grated parmesan and parsley for color. Serve meat and sauce atop a mound of pasta</Step>
        </Steps>        
        <Hint>Make the meat ahead of time, and refrigerate overnight, the acid in the tomato sauce will tenderize the meat even more. If you do this, save the mozzarella till the last minute</Hint>        
    </Directions>

    <Nutritions>
                <Nutrient>
            <Name>Calories</Name>
            <Value>1167</Value>
        </Nutrient>        
        <Nutrient>
            <Name>Protein</Name>
            <Value>71g</Value>
        </Nutrient>        
        <Nutrient>
            <Name>Fat</Name>
            <Value>52g</Value>
        </Nutrient>        
        <Nutrient>
            <Name>Carbohydrates</Name>
            <Value>101g</Value>
        </Nutrient>
    </Nutritions>
</Recipe>
```

XSL FILE

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    table, th, td {
                    border: 1px solid black;  border: 1px solid black;
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Recipe/Title"/>
                </h1>
                <h4>INGREDIENTS</h4>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Quality</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Recipe/Ingredients/Ingredient">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                <h4>DIRECTIONS</h4>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Step</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Recipe/Directions/Steps">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="Step"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                <h4>NUTRIENTS</h4>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Recipe/Nutritions/Nutrient">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have had some minor errors in your code:

- Ẁith `Recipe/Ingredients/Ingredient` you are iterating over all `Ingredient` elements. That's correct. 
  But with `Recipe/Directions/Steps` you are iterating over all `Steps` elements - which is exactly one element. But the `Step` children themselves are children of the `Steps` element. So your XPath was wrong and should be `Recipe/Directions/Steps/Step` instead to iterate over all 13 `Step`s and then select their `text()` content in the `xsl:value-of`.
- Selecting `text()` in relation to `Step` is like selecting `Name` in relation to `Ingredient` - it selects a child node. You also could use `.` instead of `text()`, but I chose `text()` because it's more illustrative.

So change your XSLT of the `Directions` subsection to

```
<h4>DIRECTIONS</h4>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Step</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Recipe/Directions/Steps/Step">
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <b>Hint: </b><xsl:value-of select="Recipe/Directions/Hint"/>
        </td>
    </tr>                
</table>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm. But why use select="text()"? Why wasnt it working the way I had coded it?

Comment: You could also use `select="."`. That would work, too. But my version is more explicit. --- It didn't work the way you coded it because you iterated (`for-each` loop) over the wrong elements `Directions` and `select`ed the wrong child `Hint` and not `Step`. So your output was pretty much empty.

Comment: Thanks. But that was actually a Typo. I was originally going with :

         <xsl:for-each select="Recipe/Directions/Steps">
        
<tr>
            
<td>

                 <xsl:value-of select="Step"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

but that also didnt seem to work

Comment: We can only tell you about the errors in your code as you post it. We can't tell whether a mistake in the code was due to bad typing or due to a fundamental misunderstanding of the language concepts, and we don't usually try.

Comment: @MichaelKay yeah i know it was just that it is sometimes confusing while editing a post. Anyways I updated the XSLT file to show what I was talking about and it still only shows 1 step. Any help as to why it happens NOW would be much appreciated

Comment: I changed my answer to relate to the modified question and tested it. It works as desired.